# Interchange of derivatives and integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

I am trying to justify the following exchange of derivatives and integrals. Suppose that $s, \theta \in [a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $\pi_\theta(s) = \max [0, \theta - s]$, so it is continuous and differentiable everywhere except at $s = \theta$. Suppose, $\eta(\cdot)$ is a density over $[a,b]$ and $f(\cdot)$ is bounded over $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(s, \pi_{\theta}(s)) \, \eta(s) ds$ is finite for all $\theta \in [\theta_{\min}, \theta_{\max}]$. I have two questions:

1) I want to justify: $\frac{d}{d \theta} \int_a^b f(s, \pi_{\theta}(s)) \, \eta(s) ds = \int_a^b \frac{d}{d \theta} f(s, \pi_{\theta}(s)) \, \eta(s) ds$.

I have read (Criteria 3.1 in https://www.gold-saucer.org/math/diff-int/diff-int.pdf) that if $f(\cdot)$ is locally integrable, i.e. $\int_K \int_a^b |f(s, \pi_{\theta}(s))| \, \eta(s) \, d\theta \, ds < \infty$ for some subset $K \in [\theta_{\min}, \theta_{\max}]$, then this holds. Is there a book or a paper I can formally cite for this result?

Are there other simpler ways of justifying this for functions that are non-differentiable (or maybe even discontinuous) at finitely many points?

2) I want to simplify this splitting: $\int_a^b \frac{d}{d \theta} f(s, \pi_{\theta}(s)) \, \eta(s) ds = \int_{s < \theta} \frac{d}{d \theta} f(s, \pi_{\theta}(s)) \, \eta(s) ds + \int_{s > \theta} \frac{d}{d \theta} f(s, \pi_{\theta}(s)) \, \eta(s) ds$.

Is this valid and if so, how do I precisely justify it?